# Org babel R: why is 'NA' replaced with 'nil'

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, r

When using R in org mode source blocks, any `NA` (i.e. missing) values in tables get replaced with `nil`. Why is this?

And is there a way to change this (globally, or at the file level)? I regularly create reports using Org Babel that are to be read by non-Org users and while they do understand `NA`, `nil` means nothing to them.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the reason lies in `org-babel-R-write-object-command`

```
(defconst org-babel-R-write-object-command "{
    function(object,transfer.file) {
        object
        invisible(
            if (
                inherits(
                    try(
                        {
                            tfile<-tempfile()
                            write.table(object, file=tfile, sep=\"\\t\",
                                        na=\"nil\",row.names=%s,col.names=%s,
                                        quote=FALSE)
                            file.rename(tfile,transfer.file)
                        },
                        silent=TRUE),
                    \"try-error\"))
                {
                    if(!file.exists(transfer.file))
                        file.create(transfer.file)
                }
            )
    }
}(object=%s,transfer.file=\"%s\")"
```

Try changing `na=\"nil\"` to `na=\"NA\"` or removing that argument.